# MongoDB regex does not match string between 2 pipes

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-negation

so i want the regex match this type of elements, this regex is created in javascript.

I assume in mongo you need `\\`  to escape instead of one

element: `toto|titi|tata|tete`

- if my value is `tete` or `titi` or `tata` or `tete` it return `false`
- if my value `to` or `ze` or `we` it return `true`
- `toto|titi` as value does not matter because i have a regex removing specials characters from value (it will become `tototiti`)

atm i used `"(^|\|)" + value + "(\||$)"` to get the opposite
 - when my value is `tete` or `titi` or `tata` or `tete` it return `true`

- when my value `to` or `ze` or `we` it return `false`

i tried

- `"(^|\|)(?!" + value + ")(\||$)"` didn't work
- `"(^|\|)(?!" + value + ").*(\||$)"` didn't work

I have no more idea, someone would have one ?

Comment: Could you clarify what *does not matter about return* means? Also, try `value + "\\B|\\B" + value`, or maybe `value + "[^|\\s]|[^|\\s]" + value`

Comment: when you are testing the regex true when it match, false when it does not match

Comment: Then, I guess, you also need to [escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the `value`.

Comment: yeah this is true i will edit the post (i already have a regex removing special characters before)

Comment: If you're getting the exact opposite of what you want, then why not just use actual JS to invert the Boolean? `!true` becomes `false` and `!false` becomes `true`

Comment: my regex is used by mongo so it doesn't look like possible to do that